# wcf service host run only on port number 8080

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, port-number

I have a wcf service and used a console app as the host for my service. when I use base address like this: `<baseaddres ="http://ipaddress:8080/" />`. When I check my service operation through a web browser I can open the service WSDL and it works fine.

But, as I change the port number to something else. The service host starts fine (with no exception of used port number or anything else). As I go to check if the service is running through web browser the service is not shown. eventually my client also could not locate the service.

app.config configuration

```
    <services>
  <service name="Natatorium_WCF.NatatoriumService"
           behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="NatatoriumService"
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="Natatorium_WCF.INatatoriumService"
              bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBindingConfig">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="NatatoriumService"
              binding="netTcpBinding"
              contract="Natatorium_WCF.INatatoriumService"
              bindingConfiguration="netTcpBindingConfig" >
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://[ServerName]:[PortNO.1]"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://[ServerName]:[PortNO.2]"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

this is the host code to start the service (console application).

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChangeServerConfigFileAttributeValue("8080", "8090");
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Natatorium_WCF.NatatoriumService)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have any firewall or port restrictions?

Comment: I don't know how to check the firewall and by the way my firewall is off @TMcKeown

Comment: How you think it should be affected by the config as it does only work with +/8080 port number @paramosh

Comment: I add my config setting in the above post. I have used tokens and set ip address and port number automatically at runtime. @paramosh

Comment: config itself looks good. might be something with the code starting the host.

Comment: the start code is simple and I attached it to the above post. @paramosh

Comment: are you sure ChangeServerConfigFileAttributeValue works as expected?

Comment: Yes I have checked it many times. @paramosh

Comment: This sounds like something related to your specific network rather than to your specific code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>

  <service name="HelloService.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService" ></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService" ></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" ></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

  </service>

</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
      <remove name="serviceDebug"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>


</behaviors>
```

Comment: i have same error that's code which i write on appconfig